# I got this error after I override the civicrm.settings.php

Tags: settings

I got this error after I add this line $civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['customFileUploadDir'] = '/var/www/testing/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload'; on civicrm.settings.php

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the path has required permission for apache to write a file in it. This errors are usually occur due to permission issues.

Comment: In the /var/www/, I don't have /testing/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload. Do I need to create? Or no need? Thanks

Comment: Make sure you use correct path of upload folder.